# Experiencing issues integrating Feather Icons through a CDN in Angular

Tags: html, angular, icons, cdn, feather

I want to use [featherIcons](https://github.com/feathericons/feather) in angular using the cdn. I followed the steps given in their git repositories but it is not working.

This is the index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Your Angular App</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      feather.replace();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<i data-feather="feather"></i>
```

Please help me fix this issue.
Thanks